# Replace a string of defined length

Tags: c#, regex, string

I'm trying to use `.Replace` method to replace one `String` to another. But it's no ordinary replacement. My original `String` to be replaced is always 8 char length, surrounded by `{` and `}` and there are 6 characters inside them, but they are not always the same. So what I'm trying to do is to replace every `String` that includes `{`, `}` and 6 more characters in-between them. Is that possible?

Comment: Can you show some example of your strings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The below regex would replace `{}` block with an empty string only if it contain exactly 6 characters.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\{[^}]{6}\}", "");
```

For 6 or more characters.

```
string result = Regex.Replace(str, @"\{[^}]{6,}\}", "");
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate it. I'll try to set this regex to be responsive only with hex-chars.

Comment: i don't what exactly you mean by hex characters. I think it would be  this `@"\{[0-9abcdef]{6}\}"`

Comment: Yes, I used this: `@"\{[0-9a-fA-F]{6}\}"`